# Why am i getting an error when calling main()?

Tags: python

so here's some code i have that is supposed to take text entered by the user and create a dictionary. Can anyone tell me why I get a traceback error when I call the function main()?

```
 def build_index(text):
    index = {}
    words = text.split()

    position = 0

    for x in text:
        if x.isalpha() == False and x.isdigit() == False:
            text.join(x)
        else:
            text.replace(x,'')

    while position < len(words):
        nextword = words[position]

        if nextword in index:
            ref = index[nextword]
            ref.append(position)
            index[nextword] = ref

        else:
            list = []
            list.append(position)
            index[nextword] = list
        position += 1


def displayindex(index):
    keys = sorted(index.keys())
    for key in keys:
        print(key + ':' + str(index[key]))

def main():
    text = input("enter text")
    build_index(text)
    displayindex(index)
main()
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback error?

Comment: Btw, you are not assigning the return values from `text.join(x)` and `text.replace(x,'')` to anything. They don't modify the string they were called from, they just return a new string with the modification you asked for

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _complete_ traceback.  That would make your question useful to others who encounter the same problem.  It would also help if you edited your title to include the name of the exception that was raised (like NameError)... again, to help others find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback error contents depends on which version of Python you're running your code in. In Python 3.x, the traceback explains why it's producing the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./prog.py", line 37, in 
>     File "./prog.py", line 36, in main
>   NameError: name 'index' is not defined

**TLDR: Need to add/change only 3 lines of code. See comments in code below**

The NameError is telling us that it doesn't know what the name `index` refers to, because it's out of the scope of the `main` method and hasn't gotten defined yet. You *could* create the `global` instance of the `index` variable as mentioned in MeterLongCat's answer, but since index *does* get created and defined when we call `build_index`, we can just return `index` after that method call, save its return value, then pass it to the `displayindex` function, as follows.

OTOH, in Python 2, as MeterLongCat points out, you're wanting to get a string from the user, which is not what `input` is for, you want `raw_input`.

```
def build_index(text):
    index = {}
    words = text.split()

    position = 0

    for x in text:
        if x.isalpha() == False and x.isdigit() == False:
            text.join(x)
        else:
            text.replace(x,'')

    while position < len(words):
        nextword = words[position]

        if nextword in index:
            ref = index[nextword]
            ref.append(position)
            index[nextword] = ref

        else:
            list = []
            list.append(position)
            index[nextword] = list
        position += 1
    return index                    # Return the index


def displayindex(index):
    keys = sorted(index.keys())
    for key in keys:
        print(key + ':' + str(index[key]))

def main():
    text = raw_input("enter text")  # Use raw_input
    index = build_index(text)       # Assign the index
    displayindex(index)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the traceback error by changing `input` to `raw_input` (for Python 2.7). You have other errors though, for example `index` in method `main` isn't defined. The following works:

```
index = {}

def build_index(text):
    global index
    words = text.split()

    position = 0

    for x in text:
        if x.isalpha() == False and x.isdigit() == False:
            text.join(x)
        else:
            text.replace(x,'')

    while position < len(words):
        nextword = words[position]

        if nextword in index:
            ref = index[nextword]
            ref.append(position)
            index[nextword] = ref

        else:
            list = []
            list.append(position)
            index[nextword] = list
        position += 1


def displayindex(index):
    keys = sorted(index.keys())
    for key in keys:
        print(key + ':' + str(index[key]))

def main():
    global index
    text = raw_input("enter text")
    build_index(text)
    displayindex(index)
main()
```

Comment: i'm using a 3.(?) version of python, sorry I didn't specify.